Django form saving wrong information to database
So in my form, when I select a time choice, for example "8 PM" it stores in the database as a different time, I've checked the form submission and it is being submitted as the correct time, but not being saved as such, is there anything wrong with the code?

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

class Booking(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    special_occasion = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=[('None', 'None'), ('anniversary', 'Anniversary'), ('date', 'Date'), ('business', 'Business')])
    meal_day = models.DateField()
    number_of_guests = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(6)]
    )
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    TIME_CHOICES = [
        ('13:00', '01:00 PM'),
        ('14:00', '02:00 PM'),
        ('15:00', '03:00 PM'),
        ('16:00', '04:00 PM'),
        ('17:00', '05:00 PM'),
        ('18:00', '06:00 PM'),
        ('19:00', '07:00 PM'),
        ('20:00', '08:00 PM'),
    ]

    meal_time = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=TIME_CHOICES)

    def clean(self):
        if self.meal_day and self.meal_day < now().date():
            raise ValidationError("Cannot make a booking in the past.")

        existing_bookings = Booking.objects.filter(meal_time=self.meal_time, meal_day=self.meal_day)
        if self.pk:
            existing_bookings = existing_bookings.exclude(pk=self.pk)
        if existing_bookings.exists():
            raise ValidationError("A booking already exists at this time on this day.")

        super().clean()  # Call parent's clean method for remaining validations

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            available_times = [choice[0] for choice in self.TIME_CHOICES]
            booked_times = Booking.objects.filter(meal_day=self.meal_day).values_list('meal_time', flat=True)
            available_times = [time for time in available_times if time not in booked_times]
            if available_times:
                self.meal_time = available_times[0]
            else:
                raise ValidationError("No available time slots for the selected day.")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)




This line
if available_times:
    self.meal_time = available_times[0]

will always set meal.time to the first available time for new, unsaved bookings, rather than the chosen time. I don't think you need that IF statement at all, you only need to raise the error if not available_times
